# NVD3 Charts in a Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am rendering multibar charts in a Boostrap carousel using NVD3.  After lots of tweaking I am finally able to create a carousel with charts in each item.  One thing I noticed is that any chart other than the active item is squished, and it doesn't render until the window is resized.  Is there a way to render the charts that aren't active?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, kind of a hack but the only way I could do it without refeeding all of my charts with data each time the carousel advances.  Just trigger a window resize event.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
var handler = window.onresize;
handler();
})
```

Comment: I just did.  If someone finds a way to do this so that the chart grows like a new chart (initial draw) rather than a resize it would look better.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me...

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```